# DevOps how to test a Pipeline Variable

Tags: unit-testing, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on a proof of concept where by I am running a Powershell script within a DevOps Release pipeline, and this Powershell script updates a Pipeline variable with a value.

I am still figuring a lot of this out but what I really want to be able to do is run some kind of test against that variable value where if it equals certain values then the release is stopped as a fail.

I have seen that within the `Publish Test Results` task:

[image]

There is a checkbox that says:

[image]

Which sounds great... I just cannot figure out how I can create a test that will take my Pipeline Variable, check it has a certain value and feed the result into this `Publish Test Result` task.

It looks like this Task is mainly used for getting results of Unit Tests built into an Applications Test project, however I would be interested to hear if anyone has done anything like I am suggesting here?

I would be grateful for any help or ideas on this!

Comment: You're going down the wrong path. If your script returns an exit code of `0`, the task succeeds. If it returns an exit code of non-zero, the task fails. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel. I was initially going to look for something like this so thanks for putting me straight on that. The powers to be would also like to know the feasibility of  actually getting the result into an xml that can be read by the Publish Test Results task as well so that it it's results are included among any other more unit type tests we may look to add. This is great for now though! Thanks!